# style="display:none" options in dropdown were selected when i click up and down arrows

Tags: javascript, html

My Code is like this:

```js
<script>
function mousedownhandler()
{
if(event.keyCode !=9)
    {
        event.returnValue = false;
    }
}
</script>
```

```html
<select onmousedown="mousedownhandler()">
<option style="display:none">opton1</option>
<option>opton2</option>
<option style="display:none">opton3</option>
<option>opton4</option>
<option>opton5</option>
</select>
```

even though the options which are hidden in dropdown were selected when i click up and down arrows, please let me know how to handle the key events in select box and handling of hidden options. these options were hide based on some condition

Answer (score 1):

You can add disabled=true and display: none for hiding an option element

```js
<script>
function mousedownhandler()
{
if(event.keyCode !=9)
    {
        event.returnValue = false;
    }
}
</script>
```

```html
<select onmousedown="mousedownhandler()">
<option style="display:none" disabled>opton1</option>
<option>opton2</option>
<option style="display:none" disabled>opton3</option>
<option>opton4</option>
<option>opton5</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add disabled attribute to your hidden options. Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/0qrpoo5m/

```
<select onmousedown="mousedownhandler()">
  <option style="display:none" disabled>opton1</option>
  <option>opton2</option>
  <option style="display:none" disabled>opton3</option>
  <option>opton4</option>
  <option>opton5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi, it is working, but i need to disable all key events on this select box. Could you please help on this